# I want a seperate link only for change password in ruby on rails !!! How Can i do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I dont want change password option in devise (edit registrations). rather, i would like to add a link or form for changing password in separate page. can anyone help me !!!

Comment: If you're using devise for your authentication, why do you not want to use the devise password change form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do, using simple CRUD methods. Create an edit view for your Users, with a Rails form that targets Devise's password fields.

edit.html.erb (in Users folder of Views):

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.text_field :password  %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

In your Users controller:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

Make sure you also have `resources :users` in your config/routes.rb file

The link to the edit view would be something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit User', edit_user_path %>
```

Comment: I am getting
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/user/edit"

Comment: i have done <%= link_to "Edit User", edit_user_path(current_user.id) %> It worked but after that again an error
NoMethodError in UsersController#update
undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Sorry, you need to add @user = User.find params[:id] into your Update function. I've edited my answer.

Comment: but, once i have changed the password... i am not getting email alert as " your password has been changed "

Comment: If you want to alert a user that their password has been changed by email, then you'll need to use ActionMailer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

I'll let you figure out the details, but you basically need to create an email and tell it to send in your controller's update function, if the user updates successfully.

Comment: Thank alot..... Can i use the password_change.html.erb from devise mailers for the created user !